# hide/show are *very* slow

Tags: jquery, css, show

I'm currently using the hide/show functions in jQuery to help filter a table into groups from a select box.

The actual code works fine, but is incredibly slow, sometimes taking a minute or two to execute.

I switched the code so instead of hide() and show() it uses `css({'display':'none'});` and `css({'display':'block'});` - **the speed difference is simply incredible, it now takes just seconds, but in Firefox the table data is all squashed for each row.**

This isn't the end of the world since here we almost exclusively use Internet Explorer, but I was still wondering if there's a way around it since a fair amount of people (myself included) do use Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In firefox to show/hide a table row you have to set the follwoing.

```
//To show
$("tr").css("display", "table-row");

//To hide
$("tr").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: this is how you should do it for IE as well as a tr should be a display type of 'table-row' rather than a block element

Comment: Actually its always better to use jquery show/hide because it takes care of all these conditions.

Comment: Many thanks, this is actually perfect! Using Firebug earlier I worked out that there were table-cell values which i tried (and of course didn't work) but this is perfect! Unfortunately I really cannot use show/hide - it takes forever to process http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/05/now-you-see-me-showhide-performance

Comment: You can also use `$("tr").css("display", "");` to show row

Answer (score 2):

The answer that mentions the duration for show() and hide() is good.  However, if you have too many rows, the difference between `show()` and `display: block` or `display: table-row` is that `show()` runs an animation for each row.  This can definitely get slow, especially so on larger tables.

If you're really trying to squeeze out performance, try looking at the source code for jqGrid or SlickGrid.  The latter one has an insanely fast filtering function that would definitely work.  If that's too involved for you, just go with `display: block` or `display: table-row` and `display: none`.  You can even create your own jQuery plugin that does showFast and hideFast so you don't have to repeat that code.

Comment: This is great advice, thank you! Just looking at SlickGrid now, looks really good :)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery API specifies a duration can be set for the .show and .hide functions. I suspect that when you set this it may solve your problem.

See [the docs for .show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

See [the docs for .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Comment: Many thanks, I had it set to (0) before so it wasn't the animation that was the problem, it was just the sheer amount of processing that killed it - http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/05/now-you-see-me-showhide-performance

Comment: @xn dx By setting the speed to 0 you are forcing jQuery to use animate to change the value, that will slow it down, just leave it blank. Also, show/hide not oly change the css but they cache the previous value to be able to restore it to its proper visibility.

Comment: Ah! I never knew setting the speed to 0 would still trigger the animation, many thanks :)

Comment: @Andrew Is it not using the default value when left blank ?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy not really, it depends on how you call it. If a duration, a plain object, or a "complete" function is provided to the call it will become an animated method, otherwise if left blank, it will just set the css. The default is only used with the above options if no duration is set. ie `.show(function(){})` will animate using the default duration/easings.